# Error: some class is not a template

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have a header file `Algo.h`. It has the following content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//some static functions
// ...

template <class Type> class Algo{
    int

    public:
        Algo(int size, int num, int plth, int theN, float** theAg, int theLN,
            float* theIn, float theeEps = 1E-3, float theEpsilonLR = 1E-3,
            int theCycle = 30, bool DebInf = false, int theT = -1, int** theX = 0,
            const char* theFileName = 0, const char* theFileNameChar = 0);
        ~Algo();

        //some methods
        //...
};

//Constructor
template <class Type> Algo<Type>::Algo(int size, int num, int plth, int theN, float** theAg, int theLN,
                                        float* theIn, float theeEps = 1E-3, float theEpsilonLR = 1E-3,
                                        int theCycle = 30, bool DebInf = false, int theT = -1, int** theX = 0,
                                        const char* theFileName = 0, const char* theFileNameChar = 0){
    //...
}
// ...
```

Then I'd like to usel it in `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Algo.h"
#include <float.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Algo<int>* construct1(const int & rt, float** & rm); //error: Algo is not a template
Algo<int>* construct2(const int & rte, float** & rm, Algo<int>* & the1, const bool & rob1); //error: Algo is not a template

//...

int main(){
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that everything should work fine, but I always get this error:

> Algo is not a template.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: At first, you're using too many parameters. This is not a good practice because program cannot be easily readed. After this you should use `Algo<int>* construct1 = new Algo<int>(...)` or `Algo<int> construct1(...)`.

Comment: Is it really necessary to prefix variable names with `the`..?

Comment: The template parameter isn't used. Possibly it's optimised away, as unnecessary, and then `Algo` really isn't a template.

Answer (score 2):

1. there is "int" which should not be there in your code. delete it, please.

   ```
   template <class Type> class Algo{
     int // here should be deleted

     public:
     ...
   ```
2. constructor of Algo has many default params, but when you define this function, these default params should not be set value in param-list. you can make the constructor definition as follows:

   ```
   template <class Type> Algo<Type>::Algo(int size, int num, int plth, int theN, float** theAg, int theLN, float* theIn, float theeEps, float theEpsilonLR, int theCycle, bool DebInf, int theT, int** theX, const char* theFileName, const char* theFileNameChar)
   {
   //...
   }
   ```
3. do these 2 fixs, it will works.( I have try it on my computer~ )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the only problem, but pay attention to how you attempt to use it.

The constructor:

```
 Algo(int size, int num, int plth, int theN, float** theAg, int theLN,
            float* theIn, float theeEps = 1E-3, float theEpsilonLR = 1E-3,
            int theCycle = 30, bool DebInf = false, int theT = -1, int** theX = 0,
            const char* theFileName = 0, const char* theFileNameChar = 0);
```

Has many parameters. The first 7 are required, the remainder have default values and are optional. However, when you try and instantiate an instance:

```
Algo<int>* construct1(const int & rt, float** & rm); //error: Algo is not a template
Algo<int>* construct2(const int & rte, float** & rm, Algo<int>* & the1, const bool & rob1); //error: Algo is not a template
```

You are passing either 2, or 4 parameters. There is no matching overload. 
You need to provide at least the first 7 parameters.